# MySQL: Create a user for reading and another for writing?

Tags: mysql, security

I have been searching for this for a while and unable to find something useful.

Is it a good practice or even important to create 2 MySQL users, one for reading and then use that whenever I'm initiating a MySQL `SELECT`.

And on the other side, create another user for writing and use it whenever I'm doing an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...?

Would this help at anything for example if I'm writing and reading to the database at the same time?

Assume we're using InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"good practice" is very hard to define - you've got a whole bunch of different things to trade off against each other.

I'm assuming that the database is being used as a back-end for some other system, and that your users don't have direct access to a SQL prompt. In that case, there are no real benefits to creating different MySQL users - it simply makes the front-end more complex, and an attacker who can reach the database and knows the "read-only" credentials almost certainly also knows the "read/write" credentials. From a security point of view, you should invest your time in network security of the database server, and secure storage of connection details.

From a concurrency point of view - two or more users reading and writing at the same time - you won't really gain anything either. This particular requirement is one of the things relational databases do very well, and I don't think it's affected at all by the permissions of the users - it's far more to do with whether you're using transactions, and how quickly your SQL executes.